# Form not validating correctly zend framework 2

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I am trying a custom configuration for a new system wide.

I'm stuck on Form validations using Filter.

Primary Question:

```
    $form      = new CrudForm($this->getEntityManager());

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $filter = new CrudFilter();
        $form->setInputFilter($filter);
        $post = $request->getPost();
        $form->setData($post);
        //$crudLogic->edit($crudLogic->populateEntity($post)->update());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        }
     }
```

This Form Never Get Validated. But what makes me crazy is that this is the Form is simple:

```
namespace Manager\Form;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
class CrudForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        parent::__construct('Crud');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $idcrud = new Element('idCrud');
        $idcrud->setAttributes(array(
            'name' => 'idCrud',
            'id' => 'idCrud',
            'type' => 'text',
        ));
        $idcrud->setLabel('Id Crud');

        $this->add($idcrud);

        $idmodule = array(
            'name' => 'idModule',
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'options' => array(
                'label' =>'Id Module',
                'object_manager' => $em,
                'target_class' => 'Manager\Entity\Module',
                'property' => 'name',
                'empty_option' => 'Choose',
            ),
        );
        $this->add($idmodule);

        $name = new Element('name');
        $name->setAttributes(array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'id' => 'name',
            'type' => 'text',
        ));
        $name->setLabel('Name');

        $this->add($name);

        $createddate = new Element\Date('createdDate');
        $createddate->setAttributes(array(
            'name' => 'createdDate',
            'id' => 'createdDate',
            'type' => 'date',
            'size' => '30',
            'class' => 'datepicker',
        ));
        $createddate->setLabel('Created Date');

        $this->add($createddate);

        $updateddate = new Element\Date('updatedDate');
        $updateddate->setAttributes(array(
            'name' => 'updatedDate',
            'id' => 'updatedDate',
            'type' => 'date',
            'size' => '30',
            'class' => 'datepicker',
        ));
        $updateddate->setLabel('Updated Date');

        $this->add($updateddate);

        $send = new Element('submit');
        $send->setValue('Submit');
        $send->setAttributes(array(
            'type'  => 'submit'
        ));
        $this->add($send);
    }
}
```

And The Filter:

```
namespace Manager\Filter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

class CrudFilter extends InputFilter
{
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'IdCrud'
            ,'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            )
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'IdModule'
            ,'required' => true
            ,'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'Int'),
            )
        ));
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'Name'
            ,'required' => true
            ,'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'      => 1,
                    'max'      =>150,
                ),
            ),
        )
    ));

}
```

}

To me surprise at all, the erros after i do $form->isValid() is returning like it:

```
array (size=2)
  'createdDate' => 
    array (size=1)
      'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)
  'updatedDate' => 
    array (size=1)
      'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)
```

So it is the problem, i not even declare validation on those fields, just for idModule and name inputs, i'm losting time on one think that i not even declare!

Where can is coming those validation?

Edit: By the way i not even echoing the createdDate and updatedDate on view, is just for database control, i not need those fields to be validated on Form scope.

Edit2: By removing the createDate and updateDate from Form, i get zero message erros, but even not validating the form! I need the form to be valid.

Comment: The First Error that's insert in those question was the the Form element and the Filter element wans't the same Identifier. You can see thats on Filter i put IdCrud and on Form idCrud. But it's the first error, i doesn't find why was validating on createdDate at all. But by the way i was able to remove those createdDate and updatedDate off from Form and Just Set those values on the Model. Was a not solved question by with this overwork i could go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - Do make sure that the database table structure does not have those fields (createdDate and updatedDate) as NOT NULL.

Second - InputFilter has more like - strict behavior.
If you want any element to be required or not, then you have to specify that explicitly.

Try setting the Filter for 'createdDate' and 'updatedDate' as `'required' => false,`

```
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'createdDate',
    'required' => false,
    ....
));

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'updatedDate',
    'required' => false,
    ....
));
```

At least this way, those messages wont be added in the errors() array.

Comment: sorry by the long time to accept your answers, but by the way you help my life with the 'required' => false, I appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue it seems you cant make it optional.

I've tried setting 'required' => false, etc but to no avail.

This seems like a bug to me.

The table DDL has nulls allowed, I try to allow Null values by setting required off, but these options are ignored.

Looks like you have to extend the DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect and force null valuses to be accepted.

Makes ObjectSelect less attractive for use in real applications though.